# PowerApps Hyperlink Display Text

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a field in SharePoint defined as a hyperlink (a link to somewhere else in the site).  When I create a customized form for the list using Powerapps, I only have the ability to include a field to store the URL address.  How do I allow the user the ability to enter the display text?  Each Hyperlink has an address and display text component. I used the SharePoint PowerApps Customize forms option.

Answer (score -1):

By default, the hyperlink display text of SharePoint HyperLink field don't show in the PowerApps custom form.

As a workaround, we can create a MS Flow to get it, check thread here: [Get hyperlink display text in SP list](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Get-hyperlink-display-text-in-SP-list/td-p/345930).

To post to the SharePoint list from PowerApps, we can use a text input to receive user input, and set the value to SharePoint using MS Flow with REST API.

Reference: [Setting and Updating SharePoint Hyperlink fields in Flow and Logic Apps](https://collab365.community/setting-updating-sharepoint-hyperlink-fields-flow-logic-apps/)